# How can I ensure that a combination of fields is unique in a GraphQL schema model in AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS Amplify for a project and we have a model defined in our schema as

```
type Account @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }, { allow: private, provider: iam }]){
  id: ID!
  account_id: String!
  holder_id: String!
  type: String!
  status: String!
  capabilities: [String]
  available_capabilities: [String]
  error: String
  user: User @belongsTo
  liability: AWSJSON
}
```

**NOTE**: **User** is another model in the schema.

We ran `amplify push` to push this schema up to our environment and this has generated the full schema along with queries and mutations for the Account model:

```
type Mutation {
  //...
  createAccount(input: CreateAccountInput!, condition: ModelAccountConditionInput): Account
    @aws_iam
  @aws_cognito_user_pools
  updateAccount(input: UpdateAccountInput!, condition: ModelAccountConditionInput): Account
    @aws_iam
  @aws_cognito_user_pools
  deleteAccount(input: DeleteAccountInput!, condition: ModelAccountConditionInput): Account
    @aws_iam
  @aws_cognito_user_pools
}
```

So this gives us the operations for creating, updating, and deleting accounts from our Accounts table (in DynamoDB).

What I'm wanting to now do is to enforce uniqueness on a couple fields of the Account model. Specifically, I don't want any two accounts to share the same combination of `account_id` and `holder_id`. I.e if we have an account in the table with `account_id` equal to "acc_123" and `holder_id` equal to "ent_123", then if we were to attempt to create a new account (or update an existing account) and have that same combination of values, the mutation should fail. However, if we were to add a new account with "acc_456" and "ent_123" then that would work (presuming that combination didn't exist yet).

The main problem is that I'm really not sure what I need to do to actually accomplish this. I suspect it has something to do with creating a custom resolver.

I looked into creating a custom resolver and found some articles about adding a lambda function via `amplify add function`.

I tried this and used the following for the code of the function (index.js):

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const { account_id, holder_id } = event.arguments.input;
  const tableName = getTableName('Account');
  const accountExists = await checkAccountExists(tableName, account_id, holder_id);

  if (accountExists) {
    return {
      error: "An account with the same account_id and holder_id combination already exists."
    };
  }

  /*
   * If no account with the same combination exists, you can proceed with the account
   * creation or other desired actions
   * I assmue we just return to continue to the next part of the resolver pipeline that
   * actually creates the entry in the table
   */
  return event;
};

function getTableName(tableName) {
  return `${tableName}-${process.env.ENV}`;
}

// Function to check if an account exists with the given account_id and holder_id
async function checkAccountExists(tableName, account_id, holder_id) {
  const params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    Key: {
      account_id,
      holder_id
    }
  };

  try {
    const result = await dynamodb.get(params).promise();
    return !!result.Item; // Return true if an account exists, false otherwise
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error checking account existence:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

I then pushed this up via `amplify push` to create the lambda function. However, I'm unclear on how to actually get this added to the resolver pipeline for both the `createAccount` and `updateAccount` mutations.

In the AppSync console on AWS, in the schema section, I can see the mutations and then navigate to the resolver pipelines for either mutation. However, if I try to add a function from the dropdown (there's an Add Function dropdown), I don't see my created function that I pushed earlier.

**NOTE** because I'm not able to add this function to the pipeline, I can't confirm if it actually works yet. It was created with the aid of Chat-GPT since I'm fairly new still to GraphQL (especially with Amplify).